# How to sync the android calendar based on app

Tags: android, calendar

Hi i am developing the android application . Now at this stage i have to sync the android calendar with my app.I am quite new in this field so need some help.I don't know whether it's possible or not. Please give me proper suggestion for this.

Comment: It's definitely possible, try looking at sync adapters - for 2.3/3.0 and earlier you're going to have to rely on the sources of the calendar provider themselves as the calendar isn't a published API until ICS.

Comment: Can you suggest me some code for it?

Comment: please checj below link for full instruction step by step
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079872/android-sync-calendar-functionality-with-own-calendar